# What was the last point in time when you would have been able to see yourself via light wrapping around the universe?

Tags: visible-light, spacetime, speed-of-light, space-expansion, universe

To put it another way, if you are floating in space and light reflects off of your back and travels outwards through the entire universe, and reaches your eyes on the other end, how far back in the universe's expansion would you have to go for this to be possible (ignoring the time you'd have to sit there waiting for the light to travel around). Or to put this even another way, at what point was the diameter of the universe smaller than the distance light can travel within the lifespan of the then universe.

I understand this question has no answer if the universe is infinite, because then it would have always been infinite, but assuming the universe is finite. And even then this question might be moot if the expansion of the universe has always been faster than the speed of light, but I'm not clear on that. And even then even then this question might not work because from what I can tell we don't know how big the universe would be if it was finite because we can't see the edges, and so we can't tell how big it would be at any earlier point. And also lets take redshift to be negligible.

Basically, if this question has an answer, I'm curious what it is. If you need to assume that the universe is 46.1 billion light-years in radius at the present time.

Comment: Although we know the size of the *observable universe*, we have no idea how much larger than this the whole universe may be (even if we assume it is finite). So I think it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @gandalf61 So like I said just assume that the universe is 46.1 billion light-years in radius right now in that case. So not just finite but known finite.